# Is there a way to add multiple parameters when using woocommerce_checkout_order_created?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed that when I try to add multiple params to woocommerce_checkout_order_created I get an internal server error on checkout when I try to pay and complete the transaction. Not sure why. My working code looks like this:

```
//----- add ecomm custom fields on placed order ----->>
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order');
function add_custom_field_on_placed_order($order_id)
{
    $center_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $key = 'location_id', $single = false);
    $guest_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $key = 'visitor_id', $single = false);

    update_post_meta($order_id->get_id(), 'location_id', $location_id);
    update_post_meta($order_id->get_id(), 'visitor_id', $visitor_id);
}
//----- /add ecomm custom fields on placed order ----->>
```

but if I try to use

```
//----- add ecomm custom fields on placed order ----->>
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2);
function add_custom_field_on_placed_order($order_id, $my_var)
{
    $center_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $key = 'location_id', $single = false);
    $guest_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), $key = 'visitor_id', $single = false);

    update_post_meta($order_id->get_id(), 'location_id', $location_id);
    update_post_meta($order_id->get_id(), 'visitor_id', $visitor_id);
    update_post_meta($order_id->get_id(), 'something_else', $my_var);
}
//----- /add ecomm custom fields on placed order ----->>
```

I get an internal server err. Not sure why. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce has its calling checkout_order_created with

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', $order );
```

File: *includes/class-wc-checkout.php*

Line: *403*

There is only 1 param.

If you want to use your own param you could use as minimum one of 3 ways:

### Way 1 | Storing a global variable

You could store and access global variable then use inside action

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order_id ) {
    global $my_var;

    $center_id = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key = 'location_id', $single = false );
    $guest_id  = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key = 'visitor_id', $single = false );

    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'location_id', $location_id );
    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'visitor_id', $visitor_id );
    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'something_else', $my_var );
}
```

### Way 2 | Using lambda

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', function() use( $my_var ) {
    $center_id = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key = 'location_id', $single = false );
    $guest_id  = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key = 'visitor_id', $single = false );

    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'location_id', $location_id );
    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'visitor_id', $visitor_id );
    update_post_meta( $order_id->get_id(), 'something_else', $my_var );
}, 10, 2 );
```

### Way 3 | Getting function params

If you calling `do_action` yourself with 2 params,
wisely check if param presented. By your calling - param presented,
by default calling - param not presented. Simple check if your param presented

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order' );
function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order ) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if ( count( $args ) >= 2 ) {
        $my_var = $args[1];
    }

    echo $my-var;
}

$my_var = 'Test';
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', $order, $my_var );
```